# R Error with using if next break in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to use a `if` statement inside a `for` loop so that if the `if` condition isn't met R will stop running the loop for that `i` value but will continue to run the whole loop, and I think I'm having a (simple?) syntax error that is giving me a different result from what I expected.

Below is my example dataset and my loop:

```
test <- matrix(ncol=3, nrow=3, data = c(10, 20, 30, NA, 10, 20, 10, 30, 20), byrow = T)
mean_fun<-function(x,y){
  mean <- sum(x,y)/2
  return(mean)
}

for (i in (1:nrow(test))){
  var1 <- vector()
  var2 <- vector()
  var1[i] <- mean_fun(test[i,1], test[i,2])
  if (is.na(var1[i]==TRUE)) next
  var2[i] <- mean_fun(var1[i], test[i,3])
  print(var2)
}
```

If I just calculate `var1` values in my loop, `var1 = c(15, NA, 20)`. I don't want to calculate `var2`  if my `var1 == NA`. In short, the result I wanted to get from this loop is `var2 = c(22.5, NA, 20.0)`.

But when I run this loop, I'm getting `[1] 22.5 [1] NA NA 20` which would mean that the loop ran okay for `i=1` and maybe `i=2` but got messed up during `i=2` or `i=3`? I can't figure out how the syntax worked so that it's giving me `NA NA 20`. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initalize your vectors *before* the loop, not inside the loop every iteration. Also, check the result *after* the loop, not every iteration.

```
var1 <- vector()
var2 <- vector()

for (i in (1:nrow(test))){
  var1[i] <- mean_fun(test[i,1], test[i,2])
  if (is.na(var1[i]==TRUE)) next
  var2[i] <- mean_fun(var1[i], test[i,3])
}

var1
# [1] 15 NA 20
var2
# [1] 22.5   NA 20.0
```